# Single common reusable class to register/deregister keyboard and setcontent offset to move textfields on keyboard popup from multiple viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

is there any way to write a common class to move textfields on keyboard shown.I found plenty of solutions but all are used with in a UIViewcontroller class but in my case i have so many forms, so i don't want to repeat the same code in all of viewController class.
any help suggesstion appreciated.please find below code that i have used.

**Keyboard Notification Registeration on viewwillAppear**

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications(){

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(KeyBoardText.keyboardWasShown(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIKeyboardDidShowNotification"), object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(KeyBoardText.keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIKeyboardWillHideNotification"), object: nil)

    }
```

**Deregister on viewwillDisapear**

```
func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications(){

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIKeyboardDidHideNotification"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIKeyboardWillHideNotification"), object: nil)


    }
```

**Set content offset for scrollview on Keyboard hide/show**

```
@objc func keyboardWasShown(_ notification:Notification)
    {

        let info:NSDictionary  = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
        let keyboardSize:CGSize = ((info.object(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size)
        var visibleRect:CGRect = viewFrame!.frame

        visibleRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height+60
        //scroll only if keybord hides the text field
        if self.offsetTextField != nil{

            if !visibleRect.contains(self.offsetTextField!){
                //+50 here is for naviagation bar height
                let textFieldPositionFromRootView = (self.offsetTextField?.y)! - keyboardSize.height+130
                let finalScrollPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: textFieldPositionFromRootView)

                self.contentScrollview?.setContentOffset(finalScrollPoint, animated: true)

            }
        }


    }

    @objc func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification:Notification){
        self.contentScrollview?.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' is a good third-party library. You don't need to add scroll view and other stuff. Its automatically managed by IQKeyboardManager.

Comment: @Nilesh thanks its working.